# Reduction time of import randomizedPCA from sklearn.decomposition in python

Tags: python

a python source are called from java. that worked true but time is very Important, all times for end python source is less than one second but time of load/import RandomizedPCA are about 3 second.this line:

```
from sklearn.decomposition import randomizedPCA
```

so i need a method for load/import this faster(Less than one second). i think a method are for load this lib on memory for ever which help for this problem, but not found it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest upgrading to the latest version of sklearn. From the [release notes](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/whats_new.html):

> `Class decomposition.RandomizedPCA` is now factored into
>   decomposition.PCA and it is available calling with parameter
>   `svd_solver='randomized'`. The default number of n_iter for `'randomized'`
>   has changed to 4. The old behavior of PCA is recovered by
>   `svd_solver='full'`. An additional solver calls arpack and performs
>   truncated (non-randomized) SVD. By default, the best solver is
>   selected depending on the size of the input and the number of
>   components requested.

```
import timeit
timeit.timeit('import sklearn.decomposition')
```

> Python 2.7: ~0.5 sec
>
> Python 3.4: ~1.2 sec

Computer: i7-3770 running Ubuntu 16.04 LTS